# Reduce, manipulating the initial value

Tags: arrays, swift, reduce

I want to create an array or dictionary with `reduce()` using another array. Normally I would use:

```
class Foo {
    var number: Int

    init(number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }
}

let array1 = [Foo(number: 1), Foo(number: 1), Foo(number: 2)]
let array2: [Int] = array1.reduce([]) { $0 + [$1.number] }

println(array2)

[1, 1, 1]
```

But if I want to manipulate the initial value I'll first have to assign it to a new array, manipulate it and return that array:

```
let array2: [Int: [Int]] = array1.reduce([:]) {
    var results = $0
    results[$1.number] = (results[$1.number] ?? []) + [$1.number]
    return results
}

println(array2)

[2: [2], 1: [1, 1]]
```

Is there a way to avoid having to create a new array and return it and directly use the initial value?

Comment: Aside from the readability concerns, you should be aware that in using `reduce` like this you’re writing very inefficient code, as the whole array/dictionary will be copied every time you modify it.  The optimizer _might_ save you.  You’d be better to use `map` in your first case, or a for loop (possibly wrapped inside a generic function) in your second.

Comment: Yea I agree. Those were just used as simple examples. If it isn't all too complicated, I prefer `reduce` over a `for-loop` since I think it looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make parameters variable in the reduce() closure:

```
let array2: [Int: [Int]] = array1.reduce([:]) {

  (var results, i) in

  results[i.number] = (results[i.number] ?? []) + [i.number]

  return results
}
```

Comment: Sighs.. it was so simple. I tried so many things overlooking something so simple... thanks :)